# django-allauth configuration doubts

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-allauth

I'm using [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) with Django 1.5.1 and I have a few questions when setting it up:

**1. Configure `urls.py`**

The docs says that you have to add the following to `urls.py` file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    ...
)
```

The problem is that I already have a custom app called `accounts` and I already use the following URL pattern:

```
(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
```

So I have a naming collision here with the `accounts/` regex URL. My question is: can I rename the `allauth` URL pattern to `(r'^auth/', include('allauth.urls'))` without having problems, or is it unsafe to do so and it'd be better to rename my own URL to something like `(r'^users/', include('users.urls'))` (and rename my accounts app to users for naming consistency).

**2. Customize allauth default templates**

What is the proper way to customize the default templates for login, etc.? I think that modifying the library directly is not the best approach. I guess it should be done through `templates` directory using some concrete directory hierarchy. Also, I don't know if some kind of `base.html` file must be provided to extend from when overriding these templates or the site's `base.html` that all pages extend can be used without problems. Could you illustrate me with this?

**3. Admin login form shows logins and logouts the first time it's accessed**

When I access the admin panel after some logins and logouts the history appears, but if I refresh the page then it disappears. I think this must be something related with the django messages:

[image: admin login]

**4. Setting `SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS`**

Is the dictionary setting called `SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS` optional or must it be set?

**5. How is the password calculated when a user signs in with a 3rd party app?**

When the user is created it has a password, but how is it calculated? And... is it useful or is it only a placeholder for this required field? Can the user use it to local login?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With respect to 1):

- There is no collision as long as there is no overlap in the fully matched URL patterns. For example: if your accounts app has a match for "/accounts/login/" then there is indeed a collision as allauth is gunning for that URL as well. But, if your accounts app simply matches other URLs with /accounts/ as prefix then you are fine.
- If you insist, you can indeed put allauth URLs below a different path. allauth uses name based URL reversal, so the new path prefix will be picked up automatically.

As for 2):

- There is nothing special about allauth templates. You can override them just like you would for any other Django app.
- Have a look at the example app. It has both Bootstrap and uniform template overrides. They can be enabled by uncommenting this line: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/901485557d4ddee30fed920f2159cdf499c39e1c/example/example/settings.py#L126
- All allauth templates inherit from a base template, called `base.html`. I would expect that your project also has a base template. Either override the `base.html` with yours, or, override `base.html` with a template that extends from `yourbase.html`

3): allauth uses the Django messages framework. See:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#expiration-of-messages -- if you do not iterate over the messages in order to display them, they do not expire. So apparently you are not showing the messages in your templates. Therefore, they heap up until the admin appears which renders (and clears) all messages collected so far...

4) Optional

5) There is no password set, meaning, the user can only login using the 3rd party account until he actually sets a password (/accounts/password/set/).

Comment: Thanks @pennersr for your fast response! OK for 1) I won't have problems here. Regarding 2) I've already set the templates in the sample project but I have one doubt: `connections.html` and `signup.html` both inherit from `socialaccount/base.html`, but I can't see this template in socialaccount I see it in account. I don't understand this. What's more I've updated my question with some more doubts. Could you give me a hand with them? And thank you for sharing this library with us! :)

Comment: The example project overrides some templates, not all.  `socialaccount/base.html` is not overriden, therefore you won't find it there. Btw, answer updated to reflect new questions...

Comment: Hi @pennersr and thanks again! OK for 3, 4 and 5. Regarding 2 (templates): I've already set it up and it's working but I don't get why the `connections.html` and `signup.html` render properly if they extend from a template that "does not exist" (`socialaccount/base.html`). Which is the "default" one for these? I already updated the `account/base.html` to extend my custom base `layout.hml` and updated this one with the blocks defined in the allauth bootstrap templates. Thanks again! :)

Comment: The template does exist -- have a look here: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/0.11.1/allauth/templates/socialaccount/base.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your answers, I'm giving you 25 rep (accept + upvote) to thank you!