# Unable to override django-allauth templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-allauth

I'm trying to override the default django-allauth templates. I've copied the templates from the allauth folder in my site-packages to my applications template directory.

The structure is as follows

```
myapp
--templates
----account
----admin
----socialaccount
----www
----base.html
```

My settings.py has the TEMPLATE_DIRS set

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),
)
```

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18811664/3725362) I'm loading my application before allauth.

Making any changes to the templates in my directory doesn't have any effect, however changing the templates in the allauth templates in the site-packages outputs the changes. I know I'm missing some very basic thing here, but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best approach, but copying the entire allauth directory into my applications root directory made it possible to override the templates.