# django allauth different layout if not authenticated

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using django with allauth and I need a different layout if the user is not authenticated. In my login.html I cannot use 'extends base.html'. Is this possible without loosing all the features of allauth ?

Comment: different layount using same template? or a different template?

Comment: two complete different layouts

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like that:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% include "subtemplate1.html" %}
{% else %}
    {% include "subtemplate2.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Allauth or not, the procedure is the same.
In your View you can check if the user is authenticated

```
def my_view(request):   
  if request.user.is_authenticated: 
      return render(request, 'myapp/index.html' {})
  else: 
      return render(request, 'myapp/logged_in.html',{})
```

However, it would be better to have different classes :

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def my_view(request): 
   if not request.user.is_authenticated: 
       return render(request, 'myapp/index.html' {})
   else: 
       return my_view_auth(request)

@login_required
def my_view_auth(request):
   return render(request, 'myapp/logged_in.html',{})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx for all the answers. I found one solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42752970/572801) which I want to share and have some opinions:

```
#  urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from allauth.account.views import LoginView

class Lvx(LoginView):
    # Login View eXtended
    # beware ordering and collisions on paths
    template_name = "accounts/login.html"

login = Lvx.as_view()

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', login),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^core/', include('core.urls')),
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/core'), name='core'),]
```

In my templates\accounts folder I now have a complete login.html page with it's own design and completly separeated from base.html

Comment: it is not clear what you try to do or why you make it more complicated then it is.