# Can I use a URL other than "accounts" for django-allauth? I already have an app named "accounts" in my django project?

Tags: django, django-allauth

Can I change the following code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    ...
]
```

to :

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^something_else/', include('allauth.urls')),
    ...
]
```

since I already have an app `accounts` in my django projects?

Is the name `accounts` deeply integrated with `django-allauth` source code?

Comment: try this `from allauth.account.views import SignupView` and then you can say `url(r'^something_else/', SignupView.as_vew())`

Comment: Thanks @Ahtisham
I found a duplicate here though:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817157/django-allauth-configuration-doubts

Comment: Did you try it ?

Comment: I am working on it, however the answer is by the creator of this app itself. I have ensured that my URL patterns do not collide for the two apps for now.